# Fitting an ellipse using astropy [Ellipse2d model]

Tags: python, astropy

I am trying to fit an ellipse using `Ellipse2D` model in `astropy` library. The fit does not work. The modeled parameters are the same as initial parameters (maybe except the amplitude parameter). See the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# fake data
num = 100
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5., 5., num), np.linspace(-5, 5, num))
e0 = models.Ellipse2D(amplitude=1., x_0=0., y_0=0., a=2, b=1, theta=0.)
z0 = e0(x, y)
print 'DATA:\n', e0, '\n\n'

# initial model
ei = models.Ellipse2D(amplitude=1., x_0=0.0, y_0=0.0, a=2, b=2, theta=0.2)

fi = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()

#fitted model?
e1 = fi(ei, x, y, z0)
z1 = e1(x, y)
print 'MODEL:\n', e1, '\n\n'

pl.imshow(z0, extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5], alpha=0.5)
pl.imshow(z1, extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5], alpha=0.2)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried a different fitter?  I wonder if this would really work since the Ellipse2D model seems to make a solid ellipse.

Comment: Yes I have tried all of them. The SimplexLSQFitter (see below) gives somehow better results, but it is still far from satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

I was waiting for the answer to this question for here or Astropy mailing list, since I was having exactly the same problem at that time.

As I couldn't find the answer, I decided not to use Ellipse2D until I figure out the problem of your/my code, but to use Gaussian2D for getting the `theta` parameter.

You may try the following code. I changed only a slight bit of your code.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

#%%
# data
num = 100
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5., 5., num), np.linspace(-5, 5, num))
e0 = models.Ellipse2D(amplitude=1., x_0=0., y_0=0., a=2, b=1, theta=0.)
z0 = e0(x, y)
print ('DATA:\n', e0, '\n\n')

#%%
# initial model
ei = models.Ellipse2D(amplitude=1., x_0=0.1, y_0=0.1, a=3, b=2, theta=0.2)
gi = models.Gaussian2D(amplitude=1., x_mean=0.1, y_mean=0.1,
                       x_stddev=3, y_stddev=2, theta=0.2)
fi = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()

#%% 
# fitted model?
e1 = fi(ei, x, y, z0)
g1 = fi(gi, x, y, z0)
z1 = e1(x, y)
z2 = g1(x, y)
print('MODEL:\n', e1, '\n\n')
print('MODEL:\n', g1, '\n\n')

pl.imshow(z0, extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5], alpha=0.5)
pl.imshow(z1, extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5], alpha=0.2)
pl.imshow(z2, extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5], alpha=0.5)
pl.colorbar()
pl.show()
print(g1.theta.value)
```

Although it does not fit the given ellipse-shaped plateau with constant amplitude, but still it gives the correct `theta` value `1.23386185422e-10` which is effectively zero. It does give correct values when I change `theta` of `e0` to some different values.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

As already noted another fitter might be better suited for this task, for example the [`SimplexLSQFitter`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.fitting.SimplexLSQFitter.html#astropy.modeling.fitting.SimplexLSQFitter).

This doesn't perfectly fit the ellipse but at least the `b` parameter almost gives a good match:

```
...
fi = fitting.SimplexLSQFitter()
e1 = fi(ei, x, y, z0)
z1 = e1(x, y)
print(repr(e1))
# <Ellipse2D(amplitude=0.8765330382805181, 
#            x_0=0.00027076793418705464, 
#            y_0=0.0008061856852329963, 
#            a=2.0019138872185174, 
#            b=1.0985760645823452, 
#            theta=0.22591442574477916)>
```

But I think `Ellipse2D` isn't a good model to be fitted, especially if `theta` differs between the models.

Comment: Thank you, indeed SimplexLSQFitter gives better (any) results, but the main parameter I am trying to find is the inclination (theta) and it fails there.

I thought that Ellipse2D should be the best to find the inclination of an ellipse, but apparently I was wrong. Do you know any better method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to suggestion by @yoonsoo-p-bach here is the working example:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# data
num = 100
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5., 5., num), np.linspace(-5, 5, num))
e0 = models.Ellipse2D(amplitude=1., x_0=0.2, y_0=0.3, a=2, b=1, theta=0.4)
z0 = e0(x, y)
print 'DATA:\n', e0, '\n\n'

# fitting procedure
fi = fitting.SimplexLSQFitter() 
#fi = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()

# gaussian fit (to estimate x_0, y_0 and theta)
gi = models.Gaussian2D(amplitude=1., x_mean=0.1, y_mean=0.2, x_stddev=1, y_stddev=1, theta=0.0)
g1 = fi(gi, x, y, z0, maxiter=1000)
print 'Gaussian:\n', g1, '\n\n'

# initial model
ei = models.Ellipse2D(amplitude=1., x_0=g1.x_mean, y_0=g1.y_mean, a=g1.x_stddev, b=g1.y_stddev, theta=g1.theta, fixed={'x_0': True, 'y_0':True, 'theta':True})

#fitted model
e1 = fi(ei, x, y, z0, maxiter=1000)
z1 = e1(x, y)
print 'MODEL:\n', e1, '\n\n'

pl.imshow(z0-z1, extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5])
pl.show()
```